# Module name exists in the framework and in local directory

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

So I have a problem. I want to import a file from a local directory having the path `dir_name/file.py` but there is already a module with the name `dir_name` **and** it also has a file in it called `file.py`. How can I get past this?

Comment: I'd probably just rename the directory & files. Unless the names you have chosen are absolutely mandatory - which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the parent folder of `dir_name` in `PYTHONPATH`. If parent folder's system path is `<parent-folder-path>` then:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<parent-folder-path>/
```

Once you are done with your work, don't forget to remove this entry from PYTHONPATH